# Porque este grupo de captura me captura un solo caracter pero no todo lo que el grupo de captura abarca?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, substring

```py
import re

#input_example
capture_where_capsule = "((PL_ADVB='la gran biblioteca rápidamente y luego llegamos allí')hacía)"


list_all_adverbs_of_place = ["de allí", "de alli", "allí", "alli", "de allá", "de alla", "allá", "alla", "arriba", "abajo", "a dentro", "adentro", "dentro", "a fuera", "afuera", "fuera", "hacía", "hacia", "encíma de", "encima de", "por sobre", "sobre"]
place_reference = r"((?i:\w\s*)+)"
pattern = re.compile(r"\(\(PL_ADVB='" + place_reference + r"'\)" + rf"{'|'.join(list_all_adverbs_of_place)}" + r"\)", re.IGNORECASE)

m1 = re.search(pattern, capture_where_capsule)
if m1:
    place_reference_string = m1.group()[1]
    print(repr(place_reference_string))
```

Porque este grupo de captura no logra capturar toda esta subcadena?

La subcadena que debería capturar seria esta:

```
'la gran biblioteca rápidamente y luego llegamos allí'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es tu expresión regular

```
\(\(PL_ADVB='((?i:\w\s*)+)'\)de allí|de alli|allí|alli|de allá|de alla|allá|alla|arriba|abajo|a dentro|adentro|dentro|a fuera|afuera|fuera|hacía|hacia|encíma de|encima de|por sobre|sobre\)
```

y lo que te está trayendo problemas es la `|` (alternancia -el *OR*).

¿Por qué? Porque el operador OR (`|`) guarda la más baja precedencia. Es decir, que el regex se interpreta como muchas alternativas (**cualquiera** de estas):

1. `\(\(PL_ADVB='((?i:\w\s*)+)'\)de allí` -este no coincide porque no está el texto `"de allí"`
2. `de alli`
3. `allí` -ESTE es el que coincide
4. `alli`
5. etc, etc, etc.

La opción 3, que es lo mismo que `r"allí"`, que no incluye a todo el inicio de tu patrón, es lo que termina devolviendo el resultado.

Por último `m1.group()` te devuelve todo el texto que coincidió (es lo mismo que `m1.group(0)`), o sea el texto `'allí'`... y `m1.group()[1]` es el segundo caracter de ese texto.

Para solucionarlo, deberías agrupar todas las opciones con `(?:` `)`:

```
(?:(?:de )?all[iíaá]|arriba|etc)
```

Quedaría la siguiente expresión:

```
\(\(PL_ADVB='([\w\s]+)'\)(?i:(?:de )?all[iíaá]|arriba|abajo|(?:a ?)?(?:dentro|fuera)|hac[íi]a|enc[íi]ma de|(?:por )?sobre)\)
```

> Y te vas a encontrar seguramente con otras cosas por resolver, pero se escapan del contexto de tu pregunta.. en todo caso hacé una nueva (y te recomiendo poner el regex final ya evaluado en tu pregunta, no hagas que alguien tenga que leer todo tu código mentalmente hasta llegar a entender cómo queda).